# Yii config file override

Tags: php, yii

I have a Yii project with a main.php config file and dev.php config file which "inherits" from it. The files are as follows:

main.php:

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');
// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'FeedStreem',
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload' => array( 'log' ),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.controllers.*',
    ),
    // application components
    'components' => array(
        'db' => array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=remote.host.com;dbname=dbnamehere',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            /*'enableProfiling' => true*/
        ),
        'user' => array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        ),
        'authManager' => array(
            'class' => 'CDbAuthManager',
            'connectionID' => 'db'
        ),
        'urlManager' => array(
            // omitted
        ),
        'errorHandler' => array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
        'log' => array(
            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'trace, info, error, warning',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params' => array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

dev.php:

```
<?php

return CMap::mergeArray(
    require(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/main.php'),
    array(
        'modules' => array(
            'gii' => array(
                'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
                'password' => 'SECRET',
                // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
                'ipFilters' => array( '127.0.0.1', '::1' ),
            ),
        ),
        'components' => array(
            'db' => array(
                'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname2',
                'emulatePrepare' => true,
                'username' => 'username2',
                'password' => 'password2',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
            ),
            'log' => array(
                'class' => 'CLogRouter',
                'routes' => array(
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                        'levels' => 'trace, info, error, warning',
                    ),
                    // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

However, when I use dev.php locally, I get the following error:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct() [pdo.--construct]: [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively  (trying to connect via tcp://remote.host.com:3306) in C:\web_workspace\lib\yii\framework\db\CDbConnection.php on line 405
```

Which tells me the dev.php did not overwrite that 'db' config option. How can I make a config file that inherits from main.php but can **overwrite** options when I merge it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i see from source code it should overwrite your config:

```
public static function mergeArray($a,$b)
{
    foreach($b as $k=>$v)
    {
        if(is_integer($k))
            isset($a[$k]) ? $a[]=$v : $a[$k]=$v;
        else if(is_array($v) && isset($a[$k]) && is_array($a[$k]))
            $a[$k]=self::mergeArray($a[$k],$v);
        else
            $a[$k]=$v;
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.8/framework/collections/CMap.php

Also official documentation says so:

> > If each array has an element with the same string key value, the latter will overwrite the former (different from array_merge_recursive).

Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMap#mergeArray-detail

Try to determine the problem via print_r the result array and look at it inner structure. I think the problem is here.

Comment: Thanks I'll try looking at the return value of the config then.

Answer (score 1):

If your project involves (or will involve) more than 1 developer, server, or customized deployment/test you have to watch out for VCS problems. For us we found it best to import a separate db.php file in `config/main.php`:

```
'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/db.php'),
```

The `db.php` file is a copy of (or symbolic link to) either `db-test.php` or `db-deploy.php` and is ignored by our VCS, while the various db-*.php files created for individual users continue to be tracked by the VCS:

```
bzr add protected/config/db-*.php
bzr ignore protected/config/db.php
```

This allows individual developers to run the system on their home machine connected to localhost databases while maintaining the deployed system's link to the central db.

Comment: This setup also enables switching between configurations without any manual file editing--just a scripted/automated file copy. Can be easily done through ssh, aliased in your favorite linx shell, etc.

Comment: Can I please ask: what about Gii ? How can we enable or disable it based on dev or production branch location ? If we are on dev branch, then gii should exist on our dev config file. If on prodution that THAT array call shouldn't exist. Any clue?

Comment: Just `.gitignore` or `svn ignore` an included config.php file that is only a file system link to the config file you want to load on a particular server. You create that link manually once per server. All your config scripts are version-controlled, but the link is not VCed. Just to clarify, it's not the git branch (svn/bzr folder), but the server instance that determines the config file you want to link to. The default version in the repo should have `Gii` disabled, so any new instances (`git clone` or `svn checkout`) won't have a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if Yii has evolved much since I tested it out, but as I recall, you need to kind of work around this issue. Here is a link which outlines a few methods of doing so. It may be worth checking around to see if things have improved.

[Blog article on environment dependent configuration](http://www.hollowdevelopers.com/2011/05/14/yii-framework-separate-configurations-for-different-environments/)

If you work with a dev, staging, and production environment which are all separate and maintained via git/svn/something else, I find it's easiest to ignore certain config files with frameworks that ignore environment settings. You have to make changes manually across these files at times, but this isn't a hardship as config files tend to remain similar once an app or website is established. This way you can tailor your settings for your environment for better debugging and testing on dev/staging, and otherwise better performance and no debugging on production.

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining which config file to use? With a `switch` statement like Steve linked to?

I use an `if` statement in my index.php to decide which config file to use based on the server environment (as mentioned in the article Steve linked). It seems to work fine for me.

Also remember that if you are running a console application, you need to tell it to use the right conig file in `protected/yiic.php` also (just like in `index.php`).

Another thing that may be happening is `CMap::mergeArray` might not be merging like you want. Again, it works for me, but perhaps when the arrays are merged it is overwriting the wrong DB config string (it's choosing the wrong one)?

One way to fix this would be to NOT have the DB creds in the main.php config file, *and just have them in each inheriting file*. So you will need an inheriting file for each environment, and no environment will run directly off of the main.php file. This way when the arrays are merged you will always have the right DB connection string.

Good luck!

Comment: My thought was to make a prod.php and keep the db out of the main, but I thought it should work as is and I liked avoiding an extra file in production if I don't really need it. I'll have to do this if the other answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 configuration files (development and production). May be you can try my configuration.

**main.php**

```
return array(
    'name' => 'My Application',
    'language' => 'id',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    // gii module
    'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password' => 'admin'
        ),
    ),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
    ),

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload' => array('log'),
    'defaultController' => 'site',
    // application components
    'components' => array(
        'user' => array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
            'loginUrl' => array('user/login'),
        ),
        'errorHandler' => array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>require('params.php'),
);
```

you can customize how to show the error log for your development and production server

**development.php** // you can customize the packages imported for development and production

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
    array(
        'components'=>array(
            'db'=>array(
                'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
                'emulatePrepare' => true,
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'tablePrefix' => '',
            ),
            'log' => array(
                'class' => 'CLogRouter',
                'routes' => array(
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                        'levels' => 'error, warning',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CDbLogRoute',
                        'levels' => 'trace, info, warning, error',
                        'connectionID' => 'db',
                        'autoCreateLogTable' => true,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    require('main.php')
);
```

**production.php**

```
return CMap::mergeArray(
    array(
        'components'=>array(
            'db'=>array(
                'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=myserver.com;dbname=mydb',
                'emulatePrepare' => true,
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'mypassword',
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'tablePrefix' => '',
            ),
            'log' => array(
                'class' => 'CLogRouter',
                'routes' => array(
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                        'levels' => 'error, warning',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class' => 'CDbLogRoute',
                        'levels' => 'trace, info, warning, error',
                        'connectionID' => 'db',
                        'autoCreateLogTable' => true,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    require('main.php')
);
```

just run the development or production configuration rather than main config

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was actually loading "index.php" when I wanted "index-dev.php".
My .htaccess redirect wasn't working for "localhost/" but it was working for "localhost/page".

I've got it working now by typing "localhost/index-dev.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Yii you can also use the CMap::mergeArray function which does what the longer version of the accepted answer does already.

The last part of my index file looks like this:

```
$configMain = require_once(dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'protected'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'main.php');
$configServer = require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'protected'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'main' . $env . '.php' );

require_once($yii);

$config = CMap::mergeArray( $configMain, $configServer );
// Set Path alias for all javascript scripts
Yii::setPathOfAlias('js', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."js/");
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

The part left out is at the top where I determine if I'm local or on the server.

Comment: I was using the `mergeArray` (it's in my question). And so was the accepted answer (he was just showing what `mergeArray` does). Also, I'm no longer working on this project but thanks for contributing.

Comment: Sure, I was mostly just sharing how I handle dev/prod settings in the same file using a flag if anyone was interested. :)